# Ember and htaccess for Refreshing

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, ember.js, firebase, ember-cli

I am working on an Ember 2.6 app and have hit a snag when it comes to refreshing the page. This looks to be a common issue so I have found and updated my `.htaccess` file as follow:

```
Options FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

So this works whenever I refresh on a URL like: http://danyuschick.com/projects

However, it does not load whenever I refresh on: http://danyuschick.com/projects/14

Here is my router:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');
  this.route('blogs');
  this.route('projects', function() {
      this.route('index', { path: '/' });
      this.route('project', { path: '/:project_id' });
  });
  this.route('error', { path: '*path' });
  this.route('loading');
});
```

And my route defining the model

```
model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('projects', params.project_id);
}
```

I'm not sure where this update would need to take place, htaccess or my router or what.

Comment: try this.store.findRecord('project', params.project_id);  - ember-data by default it will pluralize model and request for data

Comment: No luck, @kumkanillam. Still the same result of no files or styles being loaded upon refresh. No console errors though that I can see,

Comment: Though I can tell that upon refresh, the params.project_id still populates correctly.

Comment: On refresh projects/index.hbs will be overwritten by the projects/14 ..so you need to move projects/index.hbs to projects.hbs..if you dont get me, i will provide sample twiddle...

Comment: Thanks, @kumkanillam. I think I will need an example. Right now app/projects.hbs is just my {{liquid-outlet}} while my projects/index.hbs is {{component 'list' model=model}}. So I'm not sure how that would be reworked.

Comment: I hope some one with more experience will guide in right direction.it looks the problem is beyond my skill level.

Answer (score 0):

If you try this, it should work:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

What it does, is check if the the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is a file with a size, OR is a symlink, OR a directory. If not, it will rewrite the request to index.html

Comment: No change. I am still able to refresh on /projects but not /projects/14.